# Check lifecycle state

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (?) {
            ... handle ...
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (?) {
            ... handle ...
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to play around with an instance retained fragment that should handle some things during `onResume()` and `onPause()`. I have added this to the main activity, and so far it is working great, except for one thing. If I enter another Activity in the application, let's say the application settings, this fragment will still execute onResume and onPause upon screen flip.

What I need is a way to find out whether the activity that this fragment is attached to, is not in the foreground. I have tried things like isTaskRoot, but it will return true as long as these lifecycle methods are executed. Now if Android knows to put this fragment into pause after running onResume, then there must be a way to check for this from within the onResume method?

Answer (score 3):

Just use the Activity's function `hasWindowFocus()`. This worked for me. And you can use it to set a flag to complete an action for when the Activity does return to focus and check the flag in `onResume()`.

Comment: Not exactly an answer to the question, but this worked for me when I didn't want to do something in an activity that wasn't current and I couldn't track state in the host application as I don't own it.

Answer (score 2):

Activity becomes non-foreground when its `onPause()` is called.
Activity becomes foreground when its `onResume()` is called.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#Lifecycle

One way to find out

> Whether the activity, that this fragment is attached to, is not in the
>   foreground

is to have the activity to set `isForeground = false` in the activity's `onPause()` method and to set `isForeground = true` in the activity's `onResume()` method and make this flag available to the fragment through a callback interface similar to the one [described here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#EventCallbacks).   The only difference is instead pushing fragment events to the Activity, the fragment will be reading activity state (e.g., `SomeInterface.getForeground()`).

Another way is to define a public method `MyFragment.setForeground(boolean foreground)` and make the activity call this method from its `onPause()` and `onResume()` methods.

Comment: What I need is to know from the fragments onResume if it really is resuming or not. Like I said, if I change activity to my Settings Activity, then the onResume will be called in the fragment belonging to the main activity even though this is NOT the activity that I am currently in. In these cases, I should not execute anything in either resume or pause, because the fragment is not really resuming. I don't know why these are even called when the activity is in the background, but in any case, I need a way to tell from within the fragments own callbacks.

Comment: Let's look at the second approach.  MainActivity.onPause() calls MyFragment.setForeground(false), which will set  MyFragment.isParentInForeground to false.  Then MyFragment.onResume() can check if isParentInForeground is true or false and make a decision.  BTW, it is really strange that MyFragment.onPause/onResume are called when the fragment is in background :(

Comment: I can't use the Activity. This is a small library that injects a fragment into any activity where I might want it. And I think the callbacks are called due to the Retain Instance state. What I find more strange is that if I execute a class and parse the fragment "this" in my onResume() while in the background, then Fragment.getActivity() is null in the invoked class, but if I call getActivity() from within onResume() method, then it is not. If it was, then I could just use that to check the current state.

Comment: Retain Instance state is not well thought through.  For example, loaders do not work with these fragments.  Nevertheless, I still think you can use approach #1.  Look at this sample. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#EventCallbacks  Declare a public interface MyActivity { boolean isForeground()) }.  Make all activities implement this interface.  Cast activity to MyActivity in onAttach().  In MyFragment, call isForeground() from onPause() and onResume().

Comment: Your right, an Interface might be the solution for now, thanks